# what does "Symbol `_ZTISt16invalid_argument' causes overflow in R_X86_64_32 relocation" mean?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, relocation

I've compiled a C++11 application under Scientific Linux 6.4 (64bit), using a self-compiled GCC 4.8.2. The application can be compiled fine, but when running it (with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to include the gcc 4.8.2 lib64 directory so that it finds `libstdc++.so.6`), the following messages appear:

`` Symbol `_ZTISt16invalid_argument' causes overflow in R_X86_64_32 relocation
Symbol `_ZTISt16invalid_argument' causes overflow in R_X86_64_32 relocation
Symbol `_ZTISt12out_of_range' causes overflow in R_X86_64_32 relocation ``

(the demangled symbol names are `typeinfo for std::invalid_argument` and `typeinfo for std::out_of_range`)

Usually the applications then runs fine; but in some cases it crashes, apparently because it tries to catch an "invalid_argument" exception which is instead raised to the top frame.

What do these messages mean, and how can I fix them?

Comment: "R_X86_64_32 relocation" smells like you are mixing 32 and 64 bit objects.

Comment: I haven't found out what causes this problem; but it works when compiling the application with `-fPIC`.

Comment: To whoever has downvoted the question: I'm interested in the reason for the downvote!